# Sequences of consecutive numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, combinations, prime-factorization, prime-gaps

If you pick a natural number n, for example 3, and you take the string from 1,..,n and shift it via 2,...,n+1; 3, ... n+2 etc, then it looks like you will first find some strings where you can do the following:

-Take the numbers of 1,...,n.

-If i is a divisor of a j taken from your new string k,..., n+k, you can (if you want) 'couple' i to that particular j.

-You might be able to UNIQUELY couple all 1,...,n to a certain k,..., n+k (call it a bijection if you want).

Example: 1,2,3 can be 'coupled' with 3,4,5 because (3,3), (2,4) and (1,5) satisfy.

But if you keep shifting the string, it look like their will always be a string where you can't do this. In the case of n = 3: (5,6,7) won't work for the simple reason that 5 and 7 are prime.

It looks like there is some kind of a pattern in, for a given n, the first string in which you cannot do this. I've tried quite a lot of them (some might be wrong):

1: infinity, since 1 divides all numbers
2: infinity, since all two consecutive numbers contain one even number
3: (567)
4: (4-7)
5: (7-11)
6: (6-11)
7: (7-13)
8: (6-13)
9: (5-13)
10:(4-13)
11: (7-17)
12: (6-17)
13: (7-19)
14: (6-19)
15: (5-19)
16: (4-19)
17: (6-22)
18: (6-23)
19: (7-26)
20: (6-26)
21: (5-25)
22: (4-25)
23: (9-31)
24: (8-31)
25: (7-31)
26: (6-31)
27: (5-31)
28: (4-31)

Is there a reason why it has this specific shape i.e. why the last digit, which seemed to be prime always, suddenly become composite? This will, for larger n, repeat (e.g. 31), but I haven't found a number with more than 2 different primes in the prime-factorisation. Will they occur for even larger n?
Notice that the last digit only seemed to change when the chosen natural number is prime.

Writing a programme to calculate the first string for a given n crashed about n=10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An upper limit to the top of the range is the second prime above $n$, call it $p$.  As you say, this is because one prime can be associated with $1$ but the second prime cannot be associated with anything.  The lower limit of the range would then be $p-n+1$.

The first place this bound is not achieved is $17$ where the upper limit is $22$ instead of $23$.  If we try to make the assignment you need $1$ for $19$, $11$ for $11$, so have to use $2$ for $22$.  We have to use $7$ for $7$, so $3$ for $21$, and don't have anything for $6$.  This sort of chain will work whenever $6$ plus twice a prime is greater than $n$ and less than the second prime above $n$.

An interesting one to try is $31$ because there are so few primes close above it.  I believe $(8,38)$ fails because you can't use both $5$ and $7$ for $35$